# Release multiple Github repositories together

Tags: git, github, release

Is it possible to release multiple Github repositories together, with the aim of generating a single set of release notes covering all repositories?

Comment: You could use tools like `git-subtree` and `git-submodule` to stitch them all together into one super repository, but generally it's better to keep them separate, release them separately, and use your language's dependency manager to manage their relationships. We'd need to know more about how the repositories relate.

Comment: @Schwern Separate components (connected by sockets etc.) The problem is they are released together (but manually) but we'd like to generate one set of release notes covering all the repositories.

Comment: If they're so tightly coupled that they need to be released together with a unified change log, should they be in a single repository? Or the other way around; if they're in separate repositories and communicating through sockets, could they be decoupled and released separately?

Comment: @Schwern This isn't meant in a rude way: I'm not an expert with Github, just been asked to see if there's a way we can generate release notes across all repos. So my current thinking is could we create a Project, add the existing repositories to the project and then instead of releasing a single repo, we release the project? Would this then allow me to generate release notes covering all repos?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't use GH Projects. Maybe you can do something with Github Actions. Consider if you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).